# UML behavioral state diagram: entry and exit point ownership implications for orthogonal states

Tags: uml, entry-point, specifications, orthogonal, state-diagram

In UML (let's take specification 2.4.1), when considering orthogonal composite states, entry and exit points belong either to the (enclosing) composite state or to the region the entry / exit point is drawn in. So which is it?

I cannot find this explicitly in the specification, but this is what the spec says about the subject (taken from paragraph 15.3.8 of the superstructure specification): "An entry point pseudostate is an entry point of a state machine or composite state. In each region of the state machine or composite state it has at most a single transition to a vertex within the same region."

From this I infer that entry points belong to the region they are applied to. If so, how do I model entry / exit actions for the enclosing state? Do I have to repeat a 'state-wide entry action' on every entry point I use? This seems cumbersome and redundant when using many regions. Or do I have to create a 'greater' state that has its own entry / exit points (or 'entry / ...' and 'exit / ...' lines), which in turn encloses the composite state which contains the regions? This seems rather complex. Can somebody clarify this for me with a visual example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to model **actions** that are executed before entering the orthogonal regions, yes: you need to create an enclosing state (See Fig. 15.35 "Orthogonal state with regions" in 2.4.1 superstructure).

From clause 15.3.11:

> A composite state either contains one region or is decomposed into two
>   or more orthogonal regions. Each region has a set of mutually
>   exclusive disjoint subvertices and a set of transitions. A given state
>   may only be decomposed in one of these two ways.

On the other side, if all you need are entry/exit pseudostates, you can avoid that additional complexity. See the paragraph about *Composite state*, its *Description* and *Semantic variation point (default entry rule)* in clause 15.3.11.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I also saw fig 15.35, which got me on the right track, I just wasn't sure. This stems from another statement in 15.3.11, which says: "A transition to the enclosing state represents a transition to the initial pseudostate in each region." This is confusing to me, because this seems to imply that whenever you enter the enclosing state, you directly enter all regions of the substate. I was looking for a way to model behavior in between the two: after entering the enclosing state, but before entering any of the regions. Still not *entirely* sure about it :)